# Apply transparency to inlined background color on hover

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

originally, I had a style sheet which looked as follows:

```
.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  transition: background-color cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1.0) 300ms;

  &:hover {
    background-color: transparentize($green, 0.2);
  }
}
```

This worked fine. However, I had to inline my backgroundColor to make it work with a theming component.

```
import { accent1 } from 'themes/default';

export default function Button({ ...props }, {
  theme: { accent1 } = { accent1 }
}) {
  return (
    <button
      className={styles.button}
      style={{ backgroundColor: accent1 }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

However, with this hard-coded background color, I can't find any way to give it the same effect with transition without turning it into a full blown component with a `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` handler that applies an `rgba` color.

Is there any better way to do this with CSS?

Comment: Can you, instead of applying hard-coded styles, write out a block of CSS on the HTML page that mimics what you originally used using a custom class?

Answer (score 0):

The "right" (best practice) way to do this is to instead use the value of `accent1` as a classname, and specify it on your button, something like this:

```
<button
  className={styles.button + " " + accent1}
  {...props}
/>
```

And then in your CSS, you'll need to make a class for it. So if the value of `accent1` was "exampleClass", you'd need a block of CSS like this:

```
.exampleClass {
   background-color: "...";
}
```

An alternate solution that should work if you *must* keep your inline style is to put `!important` on the hover style:

```
&:hover {
   background-color: transparentize($green, 0.2) !important;
}
```

But using `!important` is generally not good practice and often leads to styling issues that can be hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Believe this is more of a general CSS question, is likely that you do not have to use inline styles. Which style takes precedent is based on specificity of the selector. As you noted, switching to an inline style won the specificity war, styles are on that *exact* element.

*Most* theming libraries use plain classes like `.btn` or `.header`. Reason being -- these are easy to beat globals. Going to make an assumption here, that your theme uses `.button` to style all buttons. Be more specific than this to win the specificity war by prefixing a type selector onto your class. This looks like:

```
button.button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  transition: background-color cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1.0) 300ms;

  &:hover {
    background-color: transparentize($green, 0.2);
  }
}
```

CSS is actually processed from right to left. So this reads as, go find all elements with `.button` class. Now select those that are also a button element type. This is much more specific and will win the specificity war with common theming libraries (like bootstrap).